# Triple integral $\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2+xy+y^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, spherical-coordinates

The following function: $$\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2+xy+y^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz, $$ where $E$ is a globe with radius 2 and center in origin.

I have got the following limits using spherical coordinates $0 \le r \le 2$, $0 \le \theta \le \pi$ and $0 \le \phi \le 2\pi$.
I'm unsure if I've calculated correctly.

Comment: Limits calculated seems fine for me.

Comment: What is the integrated function in the new coordinates and what is your integration result?

Comment: It depends on what you call $\theta$ and $\phi$. In this case, the substitution should be $x=rsin(\theta)sin( \phi), y=rsin(\theta)cos(\phi), z=rcos(\theta)$. For more information check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates

Comment: @Gowexx I have $x= rsin\theta  cos\phi $ , $y=rsin\theta sin\phi$ and $z=rcos\theta$, I think you have mixed x and y. Now do I just calculate using the limits that I have? No need for substitution and using the Jacobian right?

Comment: I have not mixed it. I'll add it as an answer

Comment: @Gowexx I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: @zkutch how did you calculate it? because there is an answer now and it's different from what we've got

Comment: @18929371. In answer I see same limit as in OP, on which I agreed. Which difference you see?

Comment: @zkutch no it ended up being correct I believe, my bad :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to symmetry
$$\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}xy\, dx\,dy\,dz=0;\>\>\>
\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}x^2\, dx\,dy\,dz
=\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}y^2\, dx\,dy\,dz
=\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}z^2\, dx\,dy\,dz =I$$
Thus
$$\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2+xy+y^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz
=\frac23(3I)=\frac23\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz\\
= \frac23 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^2r^2\>r^2\sin\theta drd\theta d\phi=\frac23\cdot2\pi\cdot2\cdot\frac{32}5=\frac{256}{15}\pi
$$

Comment: how did you think of using symmetry? Are there special cases? Can you please explain it to me

Comment: @18929371 - you could think of relying on symmetry because the integration is over a globe. Then, odd integrand $xy$ does not contribute while $x^2$, $y^2$ and $z^2$ are the same when integrated over a direction-less globe

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes it much easier for me to understand :)

Comment: I'm sorry for all these questions, but why is $$\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2+xy+y^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz
=\frac23\iiint_{\mathrm{E}}(x^2+y^2+z^2)\, dx\,dy\,dz\\$$ ? Is the $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ because it is a globe? I just want to understand it properly

Comment: @18929371 - no problem. See the edit in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much